# String reversal unexpected output in C

Tags: c

This code looks like it is supposed to reverse the string , but instead it reverses only the first character and the output is :- delloworlh

Any ideas why this is happening

```
int main()
{

    char p[] = "helloworld";
     char t;
    int i, j;
    for(i=0,j=(strlen(p)-1); i<j; i++)
    {
        t = p[i];
        p[i] = p[j-i];
        p[j-i] = t;
    }
    printf("%s", p);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your loop, you use the condition: `i<j`
So, after i reaches j/2, it starts to fix the reverse string again back to its original form.
So you must change your condition to `i<j/2+1`;

Comment: Yeah, right. But I was looking at this code for 5 min and asked me, why is he doing this such a costly way. Much easier is to create a new array and to fill it reverse.

Comment: Yaa.. but it will increase the space complexity if we create a new array .

Answer (score 1):

Change  your loop conditional statement to `i <= j-1`.

```
for(i = 0, j = (strlen(p)-1); i < j-i; i++){...}
```

Answer (score 1):

change to

```
for(i=0,j=(strlen(p)-1); i<j; i++,--j)
{
    t = p[i];
    p[i] = p[j];
    p[j] = t;
}
```